# Issue with dd.read_sql_table TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'autoload'

Tags: dask, pymssql, dask-dataframe

I am trying to fetch 7.6 million records from SQL table using python pymssql. Currently it takes over an hour to get the table records. I had attempted to run various ways for reducing this duration.

1. pandas read_sql with chunks of 100k; no improvement
2. dask with read_sql, I am getting following error.

`df = dd.read_sql_table(table_name='master_cat_table', con=mssql_db08_conn, index_col='MasterCatalog', npartitions=4)`

**ERROR**: *TypeError: Additional arguments should be named _, got 'autoload'
*

any suggestions for solving this error?

any advise on bringing down from 1 hour?

Comment: You report app level throughput of ~ 2 K row/sec, which is quite low. But you told us little about the setup. Are you dragging rows across a bandwidth limited WAN? Is this a narrow table with a pair of integer columns, or a wide table with more than a hundred columns each containing kilobytes of text? Is there a proper [PK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key)? Are there some situations where you _can_ rapidly read rows with high throughput? e.g. CREATE TABLE backup AS SELECT * FROM master_cat_table; perhaps with a WHERE clause limiting it. Help us to help you. Report details.

Comment: Please provide the actual code snippet and traceback, otherwise no one can help you. Also "fetching" the rows is probably not what you wanted to do. Why would you expect dask to magically speed this up for you anyway? See [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html#use-pandas).